# Julia: Get range (minimum / maximum values) of a multidimensional array along specific axes

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, range, julia, size-reduction

Given some array with dimensions `N1`, `N2`, `N3`, is there any way in Julia to get the minimum and maximum (the range) of this multidimensional array for the different levels of a given axis?

For example, say we have an array `my_array` with size `(10, 3, 100)` (meaning `N1 = 10`, `N2 = 3`, `N3 = 100` to keep consistency with the terminology used above). I want to get the minimum and maximum values for the three different 'levels' of `N2`. Basically, I want some more concise code that does the following:

```
N2_1_range = (minimum(my_array[:,1,:]), maximum(my_array[:,1,:])
N2_2_range = (minimum(my_array[:,2,:]), maximum(my_array[:,2,:])
N2_3_range = (minimum(my_array[:,3,:]), maximum(my_array[:,3,:])
```

So basically, you're getting the minimum (respectively, maximum) across the entire n-dimensional sub-array that's singled out by index operations like `my_array[:,n,:]`, for each of the levels `n` of the desired dimension (in this case, dimension `N2`).

I want (nicer) code that will generalize this operation to any desired dimension `N` of any multi-dimensional array, basically storing the ranges for the different 'settings/levels' of that dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `extrema(my_array, dims = 1)` (or 2, or 3), see the documentation for [`extrema`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.extrema).

You can then use `mapslices` to specify the dimensions in your call that should have colons:

```
julia> a = rand(1:10, 10, 3, 100);


julia> mapslices(extrema, a, dims = [1, 3])
1×3×1 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 (1, 10)  (1, 10)  (1, 10)
```

Note that there is currently an open issue about the performance of `extrema` being worse than calling `minimum` and `maximum` [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/31442), so you might want to check whether this causes performance issues.

Comment: I think your link was truncated. Maybe this one: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/31442

Comment: I think this is along the right track, except this appears to be getting the extremes along `dims = 2` for each of the levels of the remaining dimensions (dims `1` and `3`). Do you see the distinction between that and what I'm asking? 

I want the minimum _across_ each sub-array (dimensions `(3,1,3)` in this case). I don't want the extreme operation to be broadcast _along_ each of the different levels of the other axes. Perhaps the only way to do what I'm suggesting is by reshaping the original array first (collapsing in your example dimensions 1 and 3 togther) and then calling `extrema`.

Comment: To be more specific, the output should just a single list/array of 3 `Tuples{Float64,64}` not 3 sets of 3 sets of tuples. I want to 'squash' out the remaining dimensions in the minimum/maximum operations.

Comment: Sorry, misread - have now edited to what I believe should answer your question.

Comment: thanks, that works! and good to know about those functions in general

Answer (score 2):

Does eachslice work for you?

```
julia> a = rand(10,3,100)
julia> b = [extrema(c) for c in eachslice(a,dims=2)]
3-element Array{Tuple{Float64,Float64},1}:
 (0.00019926768773892434, 0.9978490630494796)
 (0.00035292069651315927, 0.9998983532542789)
 (0.00012135841634353106, 0.9997039922122202)
```